# Protected and package-private visibilities

Tags: java, visibility

Is there any good reason why the `protected` keyword allows for accesing the field/method from the same package (in the same way as no modifier allows it)? Why is package-private visibility included in the Java language? In my opinion it is against the encapsulation principle to allow modifying a field by a class/method located in the same package. Imagine, I would like to refactor the code and move the class to another package. 
It would break the code!

I consider both of these visibilities as some obsolete and badly prepared feature from the past. Is there any reason to use them these days and at the same time prevent the spaghetti blob?

Comment: Default access is actually pretty useful in some cases.  For instance, if you are building an API and you "trust" all of the code in the package your api code resides in to do things other could should not be allowed to do.  It's not always possible/correct to extend in this case, making protected work, so default access works nicely instead.  You end up seeing a lot of classes with default access constructors so only other parts of the API can instantiate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package-private visibility does not violate encapsulation any more than the private visibility does, but on a different level: rather than operating on the fine-grained class-by-class level, package-private visibility lets you control encapsulation at the more coarse-grained package-by-package level. This may be important in situations when you create helper classes that need to be visible to all other classes in your module, but must not be visible outside it. To you, the writer of the module, such classes constitute a private implementation detail, so if you move them to a different package, you run no risk of breaking anybody else's code; only your code may need to be refactored.

Protected visibility, on the other hand, controls access along the "vertical" lines of inheritance (as opposed to package-private visibility, which is "horizontal").

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Package-private visibility is probably the visibility level I use most often.

Classes aren't always the best unit of organization.  In many cases, you're designing two or more classes that operate closely together.  Or you have a class, but it's getting so large that you want to split it up into more than one file.

`private` access is the way to hide class-level implementation details, but it can still be necessary (and reasonable!) to have *package-level* implementation details that you still want hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Package visibility provides *more restrictive access* than public access. This allows you to expose parts of your API only to your package, without exposing it to the world.

For fields, making package visibility the default makes unencapsulated data the default. However, for methods, making package visibility the default makes it easier to use Java for beginners. Having one rule for both reduces the complexity of the language.

Comment: I know what it does. My question is if it is a good practice and not against the encapsulation principle to modify the package private fields directly.

Comment: For encapsulation, usually fields are best marked private. You are allowed to give them package access, just as you are allowed to give them public access. Having a more restrictive access than public can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no-one has mentioned TDD: without `package-private` you'd have to use `protected`, which would be terrible because you would be unnecessarily exposing loads of internals to any subclasses.

TDD seems to have been "invented" after Java was created, but the idea of testing classes obviously pre-dates full-blown TDD.  I wonder whether the Java designers devised `package-private`, precisely, for testing purposes?

The current arrangements are rather elegant really because, as every TDD-er knows, as long as the package designation of your test class matches that of the app class under test you don't even have to include your test classes in the same actual directory structure, which has two merits: 1) you don't have to mix up app code and test code and 2) you can structure your test code how you want, for example separate directory structures for unit tests, functional tests, end-to-end tests, etc.